# graphicsmagick composite and crop in the same command

Tags: crop, composite, graphicsmagick

I need to get a specific crop of an image and put it over another image at a certain position and resized.

I can crop the first image and save it to a file in one command and then I can composite the 2 images in another command.
However, I would like to do it in a single command - is this possible with graphicsmagick and how?

Here are the 2 commands I am using atm:

```
gm convert -crop 1457x973+254+413 amber.jpg tmp.jpg
gm composite -geometry 6000x4000+600+600 tmp.jpg lux_bg.png out.jpg
```

The reason for wanting this is to avoid writing to disk then reading again when all this could be done in memory.
With ImageMagick, for example, the same 2 commands would be written in a single command like this:

```
convert lux_bg.png \( amber.jpg -crop 1457x973+254+413 \) -geometry 6000x4000+600+600 -composite out.jpg
```

I am doing this with ImageMagick for now but would love to do it with GraphicsMagick.

Answer (score 4):

*If* [your reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19810759/graphicsmagick-composite-and-crop-in-the-same-command#comment29712013_19956794) is simply `to avoid creating a temporary file`, you can still do it with two commands by constructing '[pipelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29)' (a great concept invented by, [afaik](http://catb.org/jargon/html/A/AFAIK.html), Douglas McIlroy around 1964):

```
gm convert -crop 1457x973+254+413 amber.jpg - | gm composite -geometry 6000x4000+600+600 - lux_bg.png out.jpg
```

*hint: note the two `-` dashes in the two commands, and the `|` pipe*

since the `-` can be used to mean the standard output and input in the two commands respectively.

This means that *no file is created*, all should happen in the memory.

You can find this in the help (`gm -help convert | grep -i -e out -B 1`):

> Specify 'file' as '-' for standard input or output.

The use of `-` is common in unix-likes and must have been inspired by, or by something related to, the POSIX standard's [Utility Syntax Guidelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `&&` operator? Your command should become:

```
gm convert -crop 1457x973+254+413 amber.jpg tmp.jpg && gm composite -geometry 6000x4000+600+600 tmp.jpg lux_bg.png out.jpg
```

Comment: They're still technically 2 commands. The reason for wanting a single gm command is to avoid creating a temporary file (tmp.jpg in my example) which involves unnecessary read/write from/to hard disk.

Comment: i'm using gm in node, how would I translate this command to it? currently this errors out if i uncomment crop line:                                                                                
          `gm(img)
          .resize(1280)
          .composite(__dirname + '/../public/images/header.jpg')
          .geometry('+0+0')
          // .crop(1280,720,0,0)`